# maven-clean-plugin:3.3.1 won't run in Apache Maven 3.9.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have maven 3.9.3 installed on CentOS Linux 7 using sdkman but when I try to build a spring boot project using `sudo mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip` I get the error;

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.3.1:clean (default-clean) on project web: The plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.3.1 requires Maven version 3.2.5`

Am I supposed to downgrade to 3.25 or could it be using another maven version? I have another project that runs fine but can't remember how I bypassed this problem when running that project.

How do I solve this issue? Is it possible to know exactly which version of maven the project is using when building?

Comment: You are obviously running a Maven version less than 3.2.5 and not Maven 3.9.3 based on the error output `The plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.3.1 requires Maven version 3.2.5`......What does `mvn --version` print out? BTW: Why are you running your maven build via `sudo ...`?

Comment: When I run mvn -version I can see Apache Maven 3.9.3. I am running this in CentOs is there anything I can do to force it to use 3.9.3?

Comment: Have you tried to run `mvn --version` via `sudo ` as well..so `sudo mvn --version`... Can you explain what you mean by: ` using sdk` ? Do you mean by sdkman?

Comment: Yes, I get Apache Maven 3.9.3 and Maven home: /home/username/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current I use sdkman to install maven

Comment: SDK Man installs in user but not for root... so you have to start your build without `sudo ...`. furthermore you should move away from CentOS 7 because it's end of life ...

Comment: Upgrade CentOS you mean?

Comment: I was running it as root as current user was the issue. Problem solved